# removing class border on one element

Tags: css, border

I have a navigation bar which I've given properties using a class .nav.

I've added a right side border to the nav bar links, and am trying to remove the bar from the last link.

the css:

```
.nav a {
display:inline-block;
position: relative; top: 500px;
border-right: 2px solid #FFDB58;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

the html:

```
<ul class="nav"> 
<li><a href="link1.html" style="text-decoration: none">1</a></li>
<li><a href="linke2.html" style="text-decoration: none">2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3.html" style="text-decoration: none">3</a></li>
<li><a href="link4.html" style="text-decoration: none">4</a></li>
<li><a href="link5.pdf" style="text-decoration: none">5</a></li>
<li><a href="link6.html" style="text-decoration: none" border="none">6</a></li>

</ul>
```

I tried to simply add stlye in html (border="none") to remove the border, but this does not work...

many thanks - L

Comment: `border` is no longer a valid HTML attribute. If you had to do it inline, use `style="border:0"`... but I recommend Adam's answer.

Comment: You'd have to put `border:none;` inside your HTML style attribute, which you should really do as much as possible in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around, that way you can have 100% browser support. Add the border to the left side and then do

```
.nav li:first-child a { border: none; }
```

Note that you'll probably have to switch your padding left and right rules then as well, but this is the way to do accomplish what you're after.

Comment: It is incorrect to state that this method has 100% browser support, as `:first-child` is not supported by IE6 http://caniuse.com/css-sel2

Comment: It's also not supported by Lynx. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

`border="none"` is not going to do it for you.  You could use `style="border: 0"`, but even better would be

```
.nav li:last-child a { border: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6h4ZG/

Comment: FWIW, `:first-child` works in IE8 whereas `:last-child` does not.

Comment: @WesleyMurch `:first-child` does not apply to this problem exactly.  The last browser not to support `:last-child` is IE8.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - but with minimal switching of padding left and right you can have a 100% cross-browser solution by using :first-child.

Comment: @Adam not exactly 100% cross-browser support since IE6 does not support 2.1 selectors.  I think you might as well use `:last-child` since it's time to move forward and IE8 is old and not *that* popular anymore, but that's just my opinion.  If it really needs to look that way in IE8 then your solution is great but you could also just use the `style` attribute